# how to apply conditional formatting to cells based on their matching data in column A and one more condition

Tags: excel, match, lookup, conditional-formatting, multiple-conditions

column a= room number, column B person name, column C = cells needed to be highlighted
Everyone in same room (f.e 101)should be highlighted, if anyone in that room will be marked with K in column C,D,E (f.e at 13:00 person Fff in room 102 is marked K, so person Eee and Ggg should be highlighted)
If anyone from the same room is marked C or empty in columns C,D, E  then no highlight. If there is already K and the cells are highlighted, then C will be entered into highlighted cell.
i cannot figure out the formula

[image: picture of table where cells that have matching room numbers are highlighted if one has K in them]

Comment: What does " if anyone in the same room is K the others in that room". Can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: i edited the question. Sorry for my bad English, its my third language. thank you all in advance